# Editing custom user model attribute via form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm currently trying to edit a attribute in my user column on a page which isn't a devise default it's actually in a partial called **_withdraw.html.erb** I keep getting the error:

**undefined method `user_path' for #<#:0x007fd4297ab408>**

I don't understand how to fix this.

**_withdraw.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-wrapper">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="paypal-email">Your Paypal Email Address</label>
                <%= f.text_field :paypal %>
                <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                <%= f.submit %>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Any help would be brilliant. Thank you in advance

EDIT

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :offers
  resources :categories, only: :show

  root 'welcome#index'

  get '/balance', to: 'balance#show', as: 'balance'
end
```

balance_controller.rb

```
class BalanceController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user = current_user
    end

end
```

RAKE ROUTES

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                  offers GET    /offers(.:format)              offers#index
                         POST   /offers(.:format)              offers#create
               new_offer GET    /offers/new(.:format)          offers#new
              edit_offer GET    /offers/:id/edit(.:format)     offers#edit
                   offer GET    /offers/:id(.:format)          offers#show
                         PATCH  /offers/:id(.:format)          offers#update
                         PUT    /offers/:id(.:format)          offers#update
                         DELETE /offers/:id(.:format)          offers#destroy
                category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)      categories#show
                    root GET    /                              welcome#index
                 balance GET    /balance(.:format)             balance#show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the other answer,

You have to remember that calling a partial means you have to be extra vigilant about the data variables you're going to access from it.

In other words, **it's bad practice to call `@user` in a partial.** You either have to curb the usage of the partial, which negates its use -- IE is an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), or have to define `@user` every time you load the app, which is very very bad.

---

## Devise

Since you're using Devise, there are certain ways to resolve your issue.

**`current_user`**

You need to look at refactoring your code (not to rely on `@user` in a partial). Also, you need to make sure you are using the correct data in the form.

Here's a start:

```
<%= form_for current_user, path: edit_user_registration_path, method: :put do |f| %>
    <% if current_user.errors.any? %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

Devise populates `current_user` each time you send a new request. This means you can use `current_user` instead of `@user` *in this instance*.

--

You will also need to define your own path in the `form_for` helper.

As mentioned in the other answer, the `form_for` helper populates the form based on the `object` you pass it. Typically, it uses the RESTful routing pattern to determine the path to define:

From the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for):

> The URL the form is to be submitted to. This may be represented in the
>   same way as values passed to url_for or link_to. So for example you
>   may use a named route directly. When the model is represented by a
>   string or symbol, as in the example above, if the :url option is not
>   specified, by default the form will be sent back to the current url
>   (We will describe below an alternative resource-oriented usage of
>   form_for in which the URL does not need to be specified explicitly).

This means that although you may have passed `current_user`, the lack of a real RESTful routing structure will prevent Rails from populating the form code correctly. Normally, you'd have an `users/edit` path, which is lacking with Devise.

By defining your own  path (IE `edit_user_registration_path` with `PUT` method), you'll be able to access the path you need.

--

Finally, you need to see Devise's provision for allowing you [access Devise objects around your app](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app).

Specifically:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

This will allow you to call `<%= form_for resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 1):

The [`form_for()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) helper try to make a path from your `@user` variable and pass it as second argument. 
Add to the `form_for` helper second argument path to the edit action according to your routes.

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: edit_user_registration_path) do |f| %>
```

From [`form_for()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) documentation:

> The method can be used in several slightly different ways, depending
>   on how much you wish to rely on Rails to infer automatically from the
>   model how the form should be constructed.

Comment: <%= form_for(@user, url: edit_user_registration) %>?

Comment: maybe, i don't know how look path to the edit action.

Comment: check your routes with `bundle exec rake routes` and pass a right path.

Comment: Still getting 'undefined local variable or method `edit_user_registration' for #<#<Class:0x00000005fac558>:0x007f588dc09f08>'

Comment: because you should use `edit_user_registration_path` **_path** at end

Comment: No route matches [PATCH] "/users/edit" should I be putting anything in the routes file?

Comment: Added. Thanks for all the help so far

Comment: please add also output of `bundle exec rake routes`

Comment: Added routes to question

Comment: okey, no need you own form, `edit_user_registration_path` route to the devise controller with own form, add devise views with `bundle exec rails generate devise:views` and check `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` views, in this views you able to add custom attributes, but this is really another story.

Comment: <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %> is on the devise edit form